# get last item in list of child entities where condition is true

Tags: jpa, querydsl

I have the following classes:

```
@Entity
class Parent
   @OneToMany
   List<Child> childs 

@Entity
class Child
    String issuer
    @ManyToOne
    Parent parent
    Integer turn // determines order
```

I want to select the parent where the last child has a special value for `issuer`.
How can this be achieved?
When using `querydsl` my approach was something like this:

```
select(qParent).from(qParent).where(qParent.childs.get(qParent.childs.size()).issuer.eq("theValue))
```

which does throw an error.

Comment: You have to do a subselect. But how can you determine the last child in the database? What's the order?

Comment: there is an integer turn which determines the order of the childs

Comment: I don't think this works reliable without an  `OrderColumn`. That said, `SIZE(qParent.childs)` is implemented using a `SUM(child.id)` function, which requires a group by clause which messes up the query a fair amount. You'd probably have to move that into a subquery. Also, its impossible to dereference the issuer of a child unless its an entity identifier. You'd have to manually join the child and its issuer in the query.